# Shouldn't the view state be restored before presenter is created?

Tags: android, mosby

Recently I've found out that Mosby3 got released and I'm pretty glad that it has much better control over view states and all that jazz, but it came to my attention that presenter is created before view state is restored. Is this intended or is it a misunderstanding on my end? I'd assume that you'd want to restore view state before you reload data.

Answer (score 1):

No, View has no state, it just shows state of the model. You create Presenter, tell presenter that View is re-created (perhaps,because of device rotation) and then Presenter take data from model and restores state of the View.

Comment: yep, also you may have to invoke some presenter method's to fully restore the state like: LCE View State was in loading state, then you might have to call presenter.loadFoo(); again ... LCE does that automatically, but that is what onViewStateInstanceRestored() callback is good for when you have a parecelable view state restored from bundle for instance. Therfore, presenter must be created before view state is restored. That hasnt changed since Mosby 1.0